# Value not assigned in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

So in the following code a= -1  so the statement in the while loop should be -1, but the while loop is never entered. I have looped through but don't understand why the while loop is never executed. I am sure this is frustratingly simple.

```
  function translatePigLatin(str) {
    var newStr = str.split("");
    var vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    var i = 0;
    var a = vowels.indexOf(newStr[0]);
    while (vowels.indexOf(newStr[i]) != -1) {
      i = i++;
    }
    if(i===0){
       return str + "way";
    }
    else{
      str = str.substr(i) + str.substr(0,i) + "way";
   }
    //return str;
   }

   translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Comment: I've added the [tag:javascript] tag because your code looks like it. Please retag if it isn't

Comment: What do you mean by a=-1? You mean your string is -1?

Comment: `i = i++;` is weird. Use either `i++;` or `i = i + 1;`

Comment: var a  = -1 because newStr[0] is not a vowel.

Comment: i = i++ increments i then returns the original value. You're in effect not incrementing i. Leave out the i = and use a prefix increment operator instead of a postfix operator (++i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the while loop you are checking `vowels.indexOf(newStr[i]) != -1` which mean that if `vowels.indexOf(newStr[i])` is not `-1` then while loop should bve executed. and as you say the expression results in `-1` the loop should not be executed which is a expected behaviour.

Change the condition to

`vowels.indexOf(newStr[i]) == -1` if you want to execute the while loop is the value returned is -1

Comment: You are completely right.  I was sure I had run it both ways and couldn't get it to execute either way.  I knew that was too easy....